# How to detect the index of an array in my case?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-repeat` to display array.

I have something like

```
<div ng-repeat="stu in school">
    <div>{{stu.name}}</div>
    <div>{{stu.grade}}</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.school = [
    {name:'test'
     grade:'a'},
    {name:'test2'.
     grade:'b'},
    {name:'test3',
     grade:'c'}
]
```

Is there anyway I can detect the students by index? I was only provided `name` and `grade` and I want to distinguish them. For example, I want to add class '`first`' on `test` and `grade a` student and class '`second`' on `test2` and `grade b` student.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In this case, why do you need to identify the index? You can simply use ``data-ng-class="{first: stu.grade === 'a'}"``

Comment: grade:a is just an example. I could have two students with same grade a

Comment: in that case, you can add as many conditions as you want to add. ``data-ng-class="{ 'first': (stu.grade=='a' && condition2 && ...)}``

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can access the item's index and you can also generate a class based on specific property combinations on the available items.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="result in testScores">
          <span class="{{$index}} {{result.name}}-{{result.grade}}">{{result.name}} : {{result.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a working JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mattezell/douku110/3/

On a related note, TIL: how to get an AngularJS JSFiddle demo working...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-class` with condition for example if u need to add `class first` for the student whos name is `test` && grade `a` , u can use

```
ng-class="{ 'first': (stu.name=='test' && stu.grade=='a')}
```

here is the [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0YiIeE59FtzKSYnf5cNi?p=preview) for your example

**please note that your array should be like**

```
 $scope.school = [
    {name:'test', grade:'a'},
    {name:'test2',grade:'b'},
    {name:'test3', grade:'c'}
]
```